# is there an is_closure() function, in PHP?

Tags: php, closures

I have a var that I need to know if it's a closure or just a regular string, array, etc.  Of course i could

```
is_array()
is_string()
is_bool()
is_null()
is_resource()
is_object()
no? must be a closure?
```

Comment: [`is_callable()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `is_callable()` can return true on things that aren't closures -- like strings that contain the name of a function, arrays that reference a class and method, or instances of an object that implement `__invoke()`:

```php
var_dump(is_callable('sort'));
```

This yields:

```
bool(true)
```

You might do something like this, but I'm not positive it will cover all the cases:

```php
function is_closure($thing): bool
{
    return
        !is_string($thing) &&
        !is_array($thing) &&
        !is_object($thing) &&
        is_callable($thing);
}
```

If you need to actually find closures versus callables, reflection might be best:

```php
function is_closure($thing): bool
{
    try {
        return (new ReflectionClass($thing))->getName() === 'Closure';
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

$thing = new stdClass();
var_dump(is_closure($thing));

$thing = function () { return 0; };
var_dump(is_closure($thing));

$thing = 'a string';
var_dump(is_closure($thing));

$thing = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump(is_closure($thing));
```

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php says:

> **Anonymous functions**
> Anonymous functions are implemented using the **Closure class**.

https://www.php.net/closure says:

> **The Closure class**
> Class used to represent **anonymous functions**.

so they're perfectly equivalent. And indeed:
– `get_class( function(){})` returns the string `'Closure'`,
– `function(){} instanceof Closure` is `true`,
from PHP 5.3 to PHP 8.2:
https://3v4l.org/pjoF0